# Fetching data in mysqli, but showing less data

Tags: php, database, mysqli, phpmyadmin

I am trying to fetch an array from a mysqli query, but the result shown is not completed. It always shows minus 1 data. For example, I have data in the database, 1a, 2b, 3c, 4d, 5e, 6f, 7g, 8h, 9i, and 10j when I am using:

```
<?php
    $sql = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM soal LIMIT 0,10");
    $data = mysqli_fetch_array($sql, MYSQLI_BOTH);
?>

<table>
    <tr>
       <th>#</th>
       <th>Text</th>
    </tr>

    <?php
        $i = 1;
        while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($sql,MYSQLI_BOTH)){
    ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $i; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $data['soal']; ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php
        $i++;
        }
    ?>

</table>
```

The result only shows 2b, 3c, 4d, 5e, until 10j, but if I use UNION, the result will show 1a, 2b, 3c, 4d, 5e, until 9i:

```
$sql = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT 'a' as id, 'b' as soal, 'c' as mapel_id, 'd' as kelas_id, 'e' as jawaban_a, 'f' as jawaban_b, 'g' as jawaban_c, 'h' as jawaban_d, 'i' as jawaban_benar UNION SELECT id, soal, mapel_id, kelas_id, jawaban_a, jawaban_b, jawaban_c, jawaban_d, jawaban_benar FROM soal LIMIT 0,10");
```

Is there anything wrong with my code or is my database giving an error?

Answer (score 0):

you are calling below line of code twice.

```
$data = mysqli_fetch_array($sql, MYSQLI_BOTH);
```

remove the first call. As while calling the same line of code next time will start from next position in the db call not from initial position.

Hope it helps.